# Flipped / mirrored orientation of CMSampleBuffer

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I have a currently very simple camera preview app, with an `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` also consuming video frames. I perform some processing on these frames (for now nothing difficult, I just average r, g, b values for grayscaling) and draw them onto a UIView.

Upon first doing this, I noticed the view was flipped. Ah, I thought, of course the default orientation of the `AVCaptureConnection` is `LandscapeLeft`, so I changed it to `Portrait`. Now the buffer is in portrait. Upside down. And mirrored.

I can get it the way I want it by setting the `AVCaptureConnection`'s `videoOrientation` to `PortraitUpsideDown` and `isVideoMirrored` to `true`, but I have no idea why I need to do so and can find no relevant documentation or other people doing the same thing. The `AVCaptureConnection` attached to my `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` does not appear to be doing the same thing. I don't want to make this change just to see it break on other devices, so I'd like to understand what is going on here. So here goes the question: why are my `CMSampleBuffer`s flipped upside down and mirrored for an iPhone 5s back facing camera on iOS 11.4? I sincerely hope somebody can shed some light on this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few hours later and I can answer my own question.

<strike>The `CVImageBuffer` returned from the `CMSampleBuffer` has an `isFlipped` property, indicating that the y-axis has been flipped. Correcting for this flip results in a correct image.</strike>

I stand corrected! The `isFlipped` property actually indicates that the origin is where I expected it, at the top-left corner. Operating under the wrong assumption that the coordinate system was flipped, I flipped it in my processing. Then, I rendered the result into a `CGImage`, which I rendered in a `UIView`. Since the `CGImage` actually *does* have its coordinate system flipped, everything seemed well, until I tried to do other things with the image data and *those* came out flipped. Turns out the problem was the `CGImage` all along.